# Не работает анимация JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate

Если указать высоту блока в пикселях, то анимация выполняется плавно, но если высота задана в процентах, то нужный блок резко увеличивается без анимации.

P.s. Анимация должна выполняться по клику на блок

```js
function gradient(obj) {
    if ($(obj).hasClass('phoneRegistry')) {
        $(obj).removeClass('phoneRegistry');
        $(obj).addClass('phoneRegistry2');
        $(obj).animate({height: '100%'}, 150);
    } else {
        $(obj).removeClass('phoneRegistry2');
        $(obj).animate({height: 100}, 150, function () {
            $(obj).addClass('phoneRegistry');
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.phoneRegistry {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.phoneRegistry:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fff 75%)
}

.phoneRegistry2 {
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phoneRegistry" style="width: 150px;" onclick="gradient(this)">
  <strong>
      Регистратура
      <br>
  </strong>
  Строка1
  <br>
  Строка2
  <br>
  Строка3
  <br>
  Строка4
  <br>
  Строка5
  <br>
  Строка6
  <br>
  Строка7
  <br>
  Строка8
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно задать еще один контейнер с конкретной высотой блока. Примерно вот так.

```js
function gradient(obj) {
    if ($(obj).hasClass('phoneRegistry')) {
        $(obj).removeClass('phoneRegistry');
        $(obj).addClass('phoneRegistry2');
        $(obj).animate({height: '100%'}, 500);
    } else {
        $(obj).removeClass('phoneRegistry2');
        $(obj).animate({height: 100}, 500, function () {
            $(obj).addClass('phoneRegistry');
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.cont{
  height: 300px;
}
.phoneRegistry {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.phoneRegistry:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, #fff 75%)
}

.phoneRegistry2 {
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="phoneRegistry" style="width: 150px;" onclick="gradient(this)">
  <strong>
      Регистратура
      <br>
  </strong>
  Строка1
  <br>
  Строка2
  <br>
  Строка3
  <br>
  Строка4
  <br>
  Строка5
  <br>
  Строка6
  <br>
  Строка7
  <br>
  Строка8
</div>
</div>
```

Вот так уже `animate` знает сколько в пикселях ваша высота которую вы дали в процентах.

Comment: А если блок всегда разного размера?

Comment: @AlexeyPresman если высота не фиксировано то не получите плавности

Comment: @AlexeyPresman Ваши эти строки могут быть обернуты в какой нибудь тег?